# Android - Test if custom view is drawing correctly?

Tags: android, android-custom-view, android-testing

I made a custom view which overrides `onDraw` method.
Is there any way to test this method ?

The only way that comes to my mind is to try to mock the canvas and then compare pixel by pixel with the expected result. Has anybody done this before ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this article explain what are you asking for: https://facebook.github.io/screenshot-tests-for-android/

In summary, yes it has been done, in the above article you have some hints to how do it.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly the kind of thing I was looking for. I'll try it out.

Answer (score 2):

I think that you should test only drawing logic (calculations etc.). Just extract them to other classes and unit test them. Keep `View` code as dumb as possible to avoid difficulty of UI testing. You can try to test it like you wrote with Robolectric but I think that this is overkill. The most important logic (calculations) can be tested separately with lower time cost and the same certainty that code is covered with tests.